# Analogue of level structures on Hodge structures

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry, complex-geometry

It is a basic fact that polarizable (pure) Hodge structures of type $(1,0),(0,1)$ are equivalent to complex abelian varieties. In this sense, the complex modular curve ($j$-line) $Y_0(1)=\mathbf{A}^1_{\mathbb{C}}$ parametrizes polarizable Hodge structures of dimension $2$ and type $(1,0),(0,1)$. If I want to regard other modular curves $Y_0(N)$ with $N>1$ also as moduli spaces of Hodge structures, then I need a notion of "level structures" on Hodge structures. Does there exist such a notion?

Comment: These are integral Hodge structures -- right? Don't you just want to fix a basis of the reduction modulo $N$?

Comment: @AlexYoucis That's a good point. Thank you! Do you know any reference using this definition?